# Swap content on buttons click and Next / Prev buttons

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, button

I need swap content on button/number click.
If you can see on the snippet, you can access the article using buttons "1,2,3,4" or also with the **Next** and **Prev** ones. Both can access the same article. My code is already working but you need to refresh it first if you want to use the Next/Prev, or the number buttons.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-hover div").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
      $(this).hide();
  });
  

  $("#next").click(function() {
    if ($(".content5 div:visible,.content6 div:visible").next().length != 0)
      $(".content5 div:visible,.content6 div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
    else {
      $(".content5 div:visible,.content6 div:visible").hide();
      $(".content5 div:first,.content6 div:first").show();
    }
    return false;
  });

  $("#previous").click(function() {
    if ($(".content5 div:visible,.content6 div:visible").prev().length != 0)
      $(".content5 div:visible,.content6 div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
    else {
      $(".content5 div:visible,.content6 div:visible").hide();
      $(".content5 div:last,.content6 div:last").show();
    }
    return false;
  });


$('.btn-hover').first().addClass('btn-active');
$('.btn-hover').click(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  $siblings = $this.parent().children(),
  position = $siblings.index($this);
  console.log (position);
  
  $('.content5 div').removeClass('btn-active').eq(position).addClass('btn-active');
  $('.content6 div').removeClass('btn-active').eq(position).addClass('btn-active');
  $siblings.removeClass('btn-active');
  $this.addClass('btn-active');
});
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <!--Navbar-->
  <div id="section1-the-timeline" class="scrollNav">
    <div class="container-fluid section section_bg_grey">
      <div class="col">
        <div Class="button-wrap timeline  px-5">
          <a href="#section2-the-timeline" class="btn-hover">1</a>
          <a href="#section2-the-timeline" class="btn-hover">2</a>
          <a href="#section2-the-timeline" class="btn-hover">3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="section2-the-timeline" class="section section_secondary_bg">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <div class="text-center section_content">
            <div id="content5" class="content5 pb-4">
              <div class="btn-content-1 btn-active">
                <p>1</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet provident accusamus itaque suscipit adipisci</p>
              </div>
              <div class="btn-content-2">
                <p>2</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet provident accusamus itaque suscipit adipisci ullam reiciendis beatae perspiciatis impedit quam nemo asperiores, deserunt, distinctio</p>
              </div>
              <div class="btn-content-3">
                <p>3</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet provident accusamus itaque suscipit adipisci</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-5 img_wrapper">
          <div id="content6" class="content6">
            <div class="btn-content-1 btn-active"><img src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image#/media/File:Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png"></div>
            <div class="btn-content-2"><img src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image#/media/File:Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png"></div>
            <div class="btn-content-3"><img src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image#/media/File:Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png"></div>
           
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="chevron">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center middle-chevron">
      <button id="previous" class="btn btn-chevron"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
      <button id="next" class="btn btn-chevron"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="js/animation.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Programming is not about hardcoding a selector number like `.content6` into your logic. Remove or add one item and see your code fail. Instead - use `.length` to get the elements length/count. Also as soon you insert another `class="foo bar content5"` in your document - your script will also fail - since targeting the wrong elements - but it's restricted to buttons with specific ID-s which is also mining your code reusability.

Comment: .content6 is just an example. sorry.

Comment: Yes I already tried using two different class, are you suggesting that I need to use ID instead of class?

Comment: The simplest would be to wrap all inside a parent (nav, slides, prev/next buttons) and than search for the elements as descendants of that parent. That way you can have countless modules like that one inside a single page without restrictions. Otherwise you need to assign using `data-*` attributes (to your buttons) to reference the target element they control. - Also,you can create the nav buttons dynamically, and when writing HTML focus only on the content loop.

Comment: Can you help me to fix my codes. please

Comment: Also, makes no sense to use a class like `btn-active` on an element that is not a button.

Comment: thats a button. Not showing on my snippets

Comment: what is the best thing to do?

Answer (score 1):

- Have an element for your *pages* with a specific ID
- Place a DIV with data-tabs-**pagination** wherever you want
- Place a DIV with data-tabs-**navigation** wherever you want

```html
<div data-tabs-pagination="#someElement"><!-- POPULATED BY JS --></div>

<div id="someElement" class="css-pages">
    <div>Page 1 Lorem</div>
    <div>Page 2 Ipsum</div>
    <div>Page 3 Dolor</div>
</div>

<div data-tabs-navigation="#someElement"><!-- POPULATED BY JS --></div>
```

Notice how the the `data-tabs-*` attribute **matches the target element ID selector** you want to control.

A JavaScript **instance** with some optional Object with custom options could look like:

```js
// Use like:
const myTabs = new Tabs("#someElement", {
  page: 1, // Start from second page (Page index 1),
  btnPrev: {innerHTML: "&larr;", className: "btn"},
  btnNext: {innerHTML: "&rarr;", className: "btn"},
  onChange() {
    console.log(this);
  }
});

// What you can also do:
myTabs.show(0);           // Show page at index (First page = 0)
myTabs.next();            // Go to next page
myTabs.prev(2);           // Go back two pages
myTabs.next().next();     // Go forward two pages (thanks to chaining methods)
console.log(myTabs.page); // Get current page index
```

Doing so you can have as many Tabs / Pages, even slideshows or galleries in a single document that use the exact same script:

```js
class Tabs {
  constructor(selector, options = {}) {
    Object.assign(
      this, {
        EL: document.querySelector(selector),
        page: 0,
        selector,
        btnTabs: {}, // Custom attributes for tabs (navigation) buttons
        btnPrev: {}, // Custom attributes for PREV button
        btnNext: {}, // Custom attributes for NEXT button
        classActive: "is-active",
        onChange: () => {},
      },
      options
    );
    this.EL_pages = this.EL.children;
    this.EL_pagination = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-tabs-pagination="${this.selector}"]`);
    this.EL_navigation = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-tabs-navigation="${this.selector}"]`);
    this.total = this.EL_pages.length;
    this.EL_prev = this._ELNew("button", {
      type: "button",
      textContent: "Prev",
      onclick: () => this.prev(),
      ...this.btnPrev,
    });
    this.EL_next = this._ELNew("button", {
      type: "button",
      textContent: "Next",
      onclick: () => this.next(),
      ...this.btnNext,
    });
    this.EL_buttons = Array.from(Array(this.total)).reduce((arr, _, i) => {
      const EL_btn = this._ELNew("button", {
        type: "button",
        textContent: i + 1,
        onclick: () => (this._page = i),
        ...this.btnPagination,
      });
      arr.push(EL_btn);
      return arr;
    }, []);
    this._init();
  }

  // Utility function - New element
  _ELNew = (sel, attr) => Object.assign(document.createElement(sel), attr || {});

  // Fix negative modulo index 
  _mod = (n) => ((n % this.total) + this.total) % this.total;

  // Initialize
  _init() {
    // Append nav buttons to DOM
    this.EL_pagination.forEach((EL) => EL.append(...this.EL_buttons));
    this.EL_navigation.forEach((EL) => EL.append(this.EL_prev, this.EL_next));

    // Set current page
    this._page = this.page;
  }

  prev(n = 1) {
    this._page -= n;
    return this;
  }

  next(n = 1) {
    this._page += n;
    return this;
  }

  show(idx) {
    this._page = idx;
    return this;
  }

  set _page(n) {
    this.page = this._mod(n);
    [...this.EL_pages, ...this.EL_buttons].forEach((EL) => EL.classList.remove(this.classActive));
    [this.EL_pages[this.page], this.EL_buttons[this.page]].forEach((EL) => EL.classList.add(this.classActive));
    // Provide a callback
    this.onChange.call(this);
  }

  get _page() {
    return this.page;
  }
}


// Use like:
const mySectionTabs = new Tabs("#section-a", {
  onChange() {
    console.clear();
    console.log(`Current page index: ${this.page}`);
  }
});
```

```css
/*
  The CSS is entirely up to you,
  the only thing you need to know is that JS adds ".is-active" to both
  - the current page / slide
  - the current pagination button
*/

.css-pages > div {
  display: none;
}

.css-pages > div.is-active {
  display: block;
}

[data-tabs-pagination] > button.is-active {
  color: #0bf;
}
```

```html
<div data-tabs-pagination="#section-a"></div>
<div id="section-a" class="css-pages">
  <div>Page 1 Lorem</div>
  <div>Page 2 Ipsum</div>
  <div>Page 3 Dolor</div>
</div>
<div data-tabs-navigation="#section-a"></div>
```